# Will this work on mobile?

Tags: html, css, visual-studio, responsive-design

I am needing some clarification regarding this table that I'm designing.

Can it be done on mobile? And if it can be done on mobile, roughly how it will look?

[image]

Comment: Are you using Chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Google Chrome**

If you want to test if in a specific mobile will it works you can do by two ways :

1-[Remote-debugging](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging)

2-Or you just can press f12 and search `Toggle device mobile`, there you can select a mobile to see if your web is correctly rensponsive.

Here's the example : http://www.girliemac.com/blog/2014/07/28/devicemode/

**Mozilla Firefox**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Remote_Debugging

https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/08/remote-debugging-on-firefox-for-android/

Comment: Is what you looking for?

Comment: not really, but i love you too.

Comment: i know how much you care, but i appreciate it :^)

Comment: @lala Sorry if it didn't helped you :-(

Comment: could help if it was a straight yes, no answer ;)

Can that happen in a mobile phone?